# When invoking a view component from a view, what is Component?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

We are told that to use the view component, you call `@Component.InvokeAsync("Name of view component", "anonymous type containing parameters")` from a view.

Please tell me what Component represents and where is it defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Updated based on the comment thread below.)*

The `Component` property comes from auto-generated code in Razor. [You can see it explicitly noted here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/659cdc336484039f4c2e619ddbf1cc4f09459523/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Host/MvcRazorHost.cs#L43), along with other default values and namespaces. It assigns methods from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper` interface to the `Component` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I was asking... Let me rephrase my question as follows: What is the word  Component ( the word after which .InvokeAsync comes)? Is it a global variable ? Is it a property of the RazorPage or RazorView? Is it a variable injected into the view using the directive @inject?

Comment: @Ray, thanks a lot... That's what I was looking for.